# External API Request with Proxy within Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, wsgi

I have a local proxy service up at `127.0.0.1:8080`

I can make api calls with it but not within django, for some reason it works in regular python code (i.e. `python test.py`) but not in django.

```py
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
    'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8080',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', proxies=proxies)
```

django `v3.0.8` and requests `v2.24.0`

I have an assumption that WSGI somehow override's my proxy settings

The error

```py
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa922093340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, this is a docker networking issue. `127.0.0.1` within a docker container references the internal docker network not your local environment's network. Use `172.17.0.1` to specify your local environment.